# Proving probability of A and B for events

Tags: probability

If A and B are two dependent events then:
$P(A\cap B) = P(A).P(B|A) $

How can we prove this logically(NOTE: not analytically, i.e. not just using algebraic equations but with reasoning)?

Comment: How do you define the conditional probability $P(A\,|\,B)$?

Comment: @martini, sorry, a simple typo

Comment: That is the very definition of $P(B\mid A)$, there is nothing to prove logically, so it is quite unclear to me what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes more sense if you consider  sets$A$ and $B $ on a Venn diagram. The intersection  $A \cap B$ contains those elements that are in set $A $ and in set $B $

The ratio $$\frac{(A \cap B)}{ (A)}$$ is really just the probability of getting $B $ assuming you are already in $A $.

Dividing through by an the total number of elements yields the form you are familiar with.